# What ${ (%):-%n} means?

Tags: shell, zsh

I don't know what "**${ (%):-%n}**" means.

```
${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh
```

The output of `echo ${(%):-%n}` is my username.

output:
[image: output]

Comment: See: [What does `:-` mean in a shell script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30470/what-does-mean-in-a-shell-script) and [How variables inside braces are evaluated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/286335/how-variables-inside-braces-are-evaluated)

Comment: @Nick, those don't exactly help since the `${:-foo}` _without_ a parameter name is specific to zsh, and not mentioned there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `(%)` is a parameter expansion flag, specifically the one that causes prompt escape sequences in the value of the parameter to be expanded. For example,

```
% x="%n"
% echo $x
%n
% echo ${(%)x}
pi
```

The `:-` operator with no parameter name causes the following text to be treated as the value of the expansion:

```
% echo ${:-%n}
%n
```

Put them together, and you get an expression that expands to your current username. The string `%n` is the result of the parameter expansion, which also undergoes prompt expansion.

```
% echo ${(%):-%n}
pi
```